# Why am I unable to use the setter method of a base class in a derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, set, derived-class

I've recently made a switch from Java to C# and I'm wondering why I'm unable to set the property of a derived class as shown in the example below:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    private string name;

    public void setName(string name) 
    {
        this.name = name; 
    }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    setName("Car")
}
```

Comment: Your setName is Vehicle is without parameter and you are calling a parameterized method in Car class?. Also, you need a method body to call the method or an assignment call.

Comment: How `setName("Car")` straight in the class definition supposed to work? You are not calling it in any method of `Vehicle`, but in class declaration.

Comment: That code as it is won't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method can't be called directly in the class body, it has to be called from another method (the constructor for instance).

Try this:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    private string name;

    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public string setName(string name)
    {
        this.name = name; 
    }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car()
    {
        setName("Car");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either an assignment call or another method to call setName. How is the compiler supposed to know when to execute this method call? Do this:

```
public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public string SetCarName()
    {
       base.setName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting a name with no parameter seems rather useless IMHO.

Comment: Of course it does. But this code is by the OP. He changed it after I posted. My intention was to show how to call a method.